# what do I need to pass to this Subroutine in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, drawrectangle

```
Public Sub DrawRectangleInt(e As PaintEventArgs)

        ' Create pen. 
        Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

        ' Create location and size of rectangle. 
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Dim width As Integer = 200
        Dim height As Integer = 200

        ' Draw rectangle to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, x, y, width, height)

    End Sub
```

when calling the Sub with:

```
DrawRectangleInt()
```

I get an error saying that I need to pass something for 'e', but what?

Thanks.

Comment: where are you trying to call it from and the "something" MIGHT be an important clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You eaither call that sub from a paint event and pass the `e` variable to your sub, or create the Graphics object inside your sub. The Using/End Using blocks dispose of the objects correctly.

```
Public Sub DrawRectangleInt()

  ' Create pen. 
  Using blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

    ' Create location and size of rectangle. 
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 0
    Dim width As Integer = 200
    Dim height As Integer = 200

    ' Draw rectangle to screen.
    Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
      g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, x, y, width, height)
    End Using
  End Using
End Sub
```